# folders in ibm watson studio

Tags: directory, ibm-watson, watson-studio, project-lib

I am using project lib in ibm watson studio to store and save files created in a jupyter notebook(mainly csv and pkl files). The thing is that I need to store these files in different folders in my project. I could not find the way to do this properly.

```
    def my_append_data(source_data, file_name): #source data is a Pandas Dataframe
  project.save_data(file_name,source_data.to_csv(),set_project_asset=True,overwrite=True)#save csv file

    return 0
```

this is the function that i am using(for csv files)  but the files are stored in the project library without any folder specification, is there any way to create folders inside the project using project lib?

Answer (score 0):

There are no folders in Projects on Watson Studio. You cannot create files in folders on Object Storage using `project-lib`.

The [project-lib documentation](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html) states that explicitly:

> The project-lib functions can’t be used to access folder assets (files on a path in Cloud Object Storage).